# Laravel 4 Filter Images

Tags: php, html, image, laravel, laravel-4

I was told that to get png files or any other image extensions besides jpg, I would have to use a filter. I don't really understand how I would go about it and I am not really finding any documentation on it.

If someone could please show me an example that would great!

Comment: "I was told that to get png files or any other image extensions besides jpg" ? What do you mean by this exactly?

Comment: When you say "get png files or any other image" - what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Can you show some code of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: in my css i just have background: url('../images/DRCSportslogo.png');
which comes up showing that it can't find the image, but when I switch to background: url('../images/DRCSportslogo.jpg'); it will come up.

*I have both a jpg one and a png of the same image, because I realized that the only images that were coming up were my jpgs

Comment: Ask the person who told you that thing about filters to explain what he meant...CSS background images are a regular thing, almost basic, so there must be something wrong you're doing along the way (file permission, file naming, file path...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I figured out the problem, my images were corrupt somehow. I just replaced them with a new version of them and it worked.